# C# добавлять только новые  записи в ListBox

Tags: c#

Имеется поток, который добавляет в ListBox итемы из массива. Массив время от времени пополняется. Но получается так, что каждый раз в ListBox добавляется полный список массива. Что не есть очень полезно. Как можно проверить на наличие уже добавленного итема из массива, дабы не добавлять его повторно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы решаете проблему не с той стороны. Корень проблемы состоит в том, что ваш контейнер (массив) при обновлении не информирует об этом внешний мир, и вам по существу нужно выяснить, какие же собственно элементы были добавлены.

Попробуйте вместо этого воспользоваться более подходящей коллекцией, поддерживающей интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`. (Например, `ObservableCollection<T>`.) Вы сможете подписаться на добавление/удаление элементов, и будете всегда точно знать, что было добавлено.

Таким образом, необходимость в поиске отпадает.

Comment: да, лучше поздно, чем никогда. (с) ))))

Answer (score 0):

Руками сравнивать в цикле например. Если массив не сортируется, и записи добавляются только в конец, добавлять только последние n записей, по разнице размера массива и текущего числа записей в listbox'е. Можешь посмотреть в сторону [ListBox.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx), подсунуть ему коллекцию с проверкой на уникальность и т.д., на что фантазии хватит.

Answer (score 0):

TListBox унаследовал от TStringList свойство Duplicate, имеющее значения:

1. dupIgnore - игнорировать добавление дубликата;
2. dupAccept - разрешить добавление дубликата;
3. dupError - генерить исключение при попытке добавления дубликата.

По крайней мере, так в С Builder. Может и в С# так же.